# Visual Studio shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a Visual Studio shortcut to highlight the current file in Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Resharper:

> Shift + Alt + L

Comment: he is asking about VS only, I guess.

Answer (score 14):

You can enable this option to always highlight the current (active) file:

> Tools -> Options -> Projects and
>   Solutions -> Track Active Item in
>   Solution Explorer

To my knowledge there's no shortcut to go to it directly, however you could bind your own key combination by going to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`, search for `View.TrackActivityInSolutionExplorer` then assign a shortcut to it. The downside to this approach is that it toggles the option on and off rather than perform a one time highlight of the active file.

Alternately, you can use a macro to accomplish what you originally asked about. This blog post provides such a macro: [Visual Studio Macro: Locate Item in Solution Explorer on Demand](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/visual-studio-macro-track-item-in-solution-explorer-on-demand/).

Comment: awesome! thx. I assigned it to a shortcut key, that works well enough.

Answer (score 3):

Tools – Options – Projects and Solutions – Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

Answer (score 2):

the option for auto-sync is:

Tools|Options|Projects and Solutions|General|Track Active Item in Solution Explorer

this will give an outline of the class or file you are currently working on